# Regex test if value is valid format

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a task where I need to check if a value is properly quoted CSV column:

cases:

1. no quotation        - OK
2. "with quotation"    - OK
3. "opening quote      - Not Good
4. improper"quote"     - Not Good
5. closing quote"      - Not Good

CSV flags an error like below:

```
Illegal quoting in line 5. (CSV::MalformedCSVError)
```

Question: How would I get to have this working using a single regex? I need to flag error for cases 3-5.

And if you have any idea what should be checked if a CSV value is valid or not, please tell so.

**EDIT**: I have added 2 scenarios/cases below:

6. "quote "inside quotes"    - Not Good
7. "quotes ""inside quotes"  - Not Good

**EDIT**: added 1 more case:

8. "" - OK

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: How does your csv format handle quoted quotes? I have seen `""` double quotes or `\"` escaped quotes.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub I just do trial and error on this https://regex101.com/r/zIYlDL/1

Comment: @SebastianProske it processes `""` without escapes

Comment: @SebastianProske +1 that was a good question, but CSV doesn't really look at it as valid even escaped with `\"`

Comment: @jck seems i missunderstood your first comment to my question. Deleted my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without considering escaped quotes :

```
/^("[^"]*"|[^"]+)$/m
```

See it [here](https://regex101.com/r/rQ5k3P/2).

It means :

- beginning of line

  - 1 quote + anything except quote + 1 quote, or
  - anything except quote (at least one character)
- end of the line

Comment: I find your answer the simplest and closest to what I need, thank you! But now, I added 3 more cases, please check updated question. cases 6 & 7 are okay.. I am just having a problem with case 8 where `""` should be a valid one..

Answer (score 1):

`^"{1}.+"{1}$|^[^"]*$`

This matches all lines either starting and ending with one quotation mark, or lines not including quotation marks at all.
[demo](https://regex101.com/r/f3UDUq/1)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems correct until I added the last case #8 above (updated question) I tailored it to change the `+` -> `*` and it worked `^"{1}.*"{1}$|^[^"]*$`